# Swagger attempting to expose API within dependencies causing internal service error

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

When attempting to set up swagger, I get the following 'unhandled exception' after navigating to 'swagger/v1/swagger.json':

> NotSupportedException: HTTP method "POST" & path "connect/authorize" >overloaded by actions - (references to 3 API)
>
> Actions require unique method/path combination for Swagger 2.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround

This would otherwise be helpful but the root of this issue lies in the fact that this error message is referencing API that are defined within dependencies under the NuGet branch within my VS 2017 project. Is their a way in which I can tell swagger to ignore the API or anything that may resemble API in the projects dependencies branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Considering that the API is defined within dependency libraries many of the more common solutions i.e `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` (tag appended to the API definition) will not suffice.

In order to resolve issues with unique method/path combos when the API are outside of the scope of your project (dependencies) alter the ConfigureServices() method as follows:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API WSVAP (WebSmartView)", Version = "v1" });
    c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
});
```